# Does the Apple Music User Token change for every authentication?

Tags: apple-music

I'm trying to identify a user by storing the Apple Music User Token on a database. Is this token the same for an Apple Music user over multiple authentications?

I seem to have run into a hiccup here - over the course of the development (me being the only developer), I noticed four different user tokens registered on the database, despite only using one login. I want to double check if the User Token is in fact not the same over multiple authentications before I move to a different method of identification. Also, is there any other way of identifying a user similar to using the Apple Music User Token, as I'm trying to avoid using a login.